# Linux, capture word between two words

Tags: unix

I have one file:

file.txt

```
101|aaa {rating=1, dept=10, date=10/02/2013, com=11}
106|bbb {rating=2, dept=11, date=10/03/2013, com=11}
103|vvv {rating=3, dept=12, date=10/03/2013, com=11}
102|aaa {rating=1, dept=10, date=10/04/2013, com=11}
109|bbb {rating=2, dept=11, date=10/05/2013, com=11}
104|bbb {rating=2, dept=11, date=10/07/2013, com=11}
```

I am greping it based on:

```
for i in  `cat file.txt | grep -i "|aaa "`
do
    echo `echo $i|cut -d' ' -f1`"|" `sed -n '/date=/,/, com/p' $i` >> output.txt
done
```

This error occurs

```
"/sysdate=/,/systime/p: No such file or directory"
```

Please help me?

The output should be:

output.txt

```
101|aaa|10/02/2013
102|aaa|10/04/2013
```

Comment: "some error is coming", what error is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is way better for these cases:

```
$ awk -F"[ =,]" -v OFS="|" '/aaa/{print $1, $9}' a
101|aaa|10/02/2013
102|aaa|10/04/2013
```

This sets field separators to either space, `=` or `,` and fetches the first and 9th fields, whenever the text `aaa` is found in the line.